# state uses with authentication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

i'm new in coding and i I still have a problem with if else condition, i have 2 authentication and one back end , one for react native and one for react ,
in Login i want to add is_store , i want to tell the system that if the username & password correct and is_sore = true , make him logged in and if the password right and the username right BUT is_store = false don't logged him in

i'm trying to pass is_store to Login component 
i tried  if condition but it give me wrong alert

Signup component

```
class RegistationForm extends Component {
  state = {
    username: "",
    phone_number: "",
    password: "",
    email: "",
    is_store: true <--- i want to pass it to Login 
  };

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.errors.length && this.props.resetError();
  }
  changeHandler = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  submitHandler = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.signup(this.state, this.props.history);
  }; 
render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div
          style={{ marginTop: "125px" }}
          className="card o-hidden border-0 shadow-lg   col-12"
        >
          <div className="card-body p-0">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-lg-5 d-none d-lg-block bg-register-image  col-12" />
              <div className="col-lg-7  col-12">
                <div className="p-5">
                  <div className="text-center  col-12">
                    <h1 className="h4 text-gray-900 mb-4  col-12">
                      إنشاء حساب جديد
                    </h1>
                  </div>
                  <div className="text-center  col-12">
                    {!!this.props.errors.length && (
                      <div className="text-left alert alert-danger">
                        {this.props.errors.map(error => (
                          <li key={error}>{error}</li>
                        ))}
                      </div>
                    )}
                  </div>
                  <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
                    <div className="form-group row">
                      <div className="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                        <Input
                          name="username"
                          value={this.state.username}
                          onChange={this.changeHandler}
                          className="form-control form-control-user"
                          placeholder=" السجل التجاري"
                          required
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div className="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                        <Input
                          name="phone_number"
                          value={this.state.phone_number}
                          type="tel"
                          onChange={this.changeHandler}
                          className="form-control form-control-user"
                          placeholder="Mobile Ex: 966555555555"
                          required
                          pattern="[0-9]{12}"
                        />
                      </div>
                      <br />
                      <br />

                      <div className="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                        <Input
                          name="password"
                          value={this.state.password}
                          onChange={this.changeHandler}
                          type="password"
                          className="form-control form-control-user"
                          placeholder="الرقم السري"
                          required
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div className="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0 ">
                        <Input
                          name="email"
                          value={this.state.email}
                          onChange={this.changeHandler}
                          type="email"
                          className="form-control form-control-user"
                          placeholder="الإيميل"
                          required
                        />
                      </div>

                      <div className="col-12">
                        <button
                          style={{ padding: 9, marginTop: 20 }}
                          type="submit"
                          className="btn btn-success col-12 "
                        >
                          إنشئ حساب
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                  <div className="text-center">
                    <Link to="/login" className="small">
                      املك حساب من قبل: تسجيل الدخول
                    </Link>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Login component

```
class Login extends Component {
  state = {
    username: "",
    password: "",
    is_store: false <-- is here the right place?
  };

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.errors.length && this.props.resetError();
  }
  changeHandler = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  submitHandler = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
## here is what i'm trying to do with is_store 
    if (this.state.is_store === true) {
      this.props.login(this.state, this.props.history);
    } else {
      alert("Wrong");
    }
  };
render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row justify-content-center" style={{ marginTop: 125 }}>
          <div className="col-xl-10 col-lg-12 col-md-9">
            <div className="card o-hidden border-0 shadow-lg my-5">
              <div className="card-body p-0">
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-lg-6 d-none d-lg-block bg-login-image" />
                  <div className="col-lg-6">
                    <div className="p-5">
                      <div className="text-left">
                        <h1 className="h4 text-gray-900 mb-4">تسجيل الدخول</h1>
                        {!!this.props.errors.length && (
                          <div className="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                            {this.props.errors.map(error => (
                              <li key={error}>{error}</li>
                            ))}
                          </div>
                        )}
                      </div>
                      <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
                        <div
                          className="form-group col-12"
                          style={{ padding: 0 }}
                        >
                          <Input
                            name="username"
                            className="form-control form-control-user"
                            onChange={this.changeHandler}
                            value={this.state.username}
                            placeholder="رقم السجل التجاري"
                          />
                        </div>

                        <div
                          className="form-group col-12"
                          style={{ padding: 0 }}
                        >
                          <Input
                            type="password"
                            className="form-control form-control-user"
                            name="password"
                            value={this.state.passsword}
                            onChange={this.changeHandler}
                            placeholder="الرقم السري"
                          />
                        </div>

                        <button
                          style={{ padding: 9 }}
                          type="submit"
                          className="btn btn-primary col-12"
                        >
                          دخول
                        </button>

                        <hr />
                      </form>
                      <hr />

                      <div className="text-center">
                        <NavLink to={`/signup`}>إنشاء حساب جديد</NavLink>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

this is authentication actions

```
export const login = (userData, history) => {
  return async dispatch => {
    try {
      let response = await instance.post("user/login/", userData);
      let user = response.data;
      setAuthToken(user.token);
      let decodedUser = jwt_decode(user.token);
      dispatch(setCurrentUser(decodedUser));
      history.push("/home");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error", error);
      dispatch(setErrors(error.response.data));
    }
  };
};
```

thank you

Comment: is the login component a child of the registration form? can you post the render method for yoour registration component

Comment: i added both login & signup

Comment: since login isnt a direct child of the registration form you cant pass it through props. If I was you I would look into Redux as mentioned by Alok. https://redux.js.org/. This gives you access to a centralized state which you can use across all components

Comment: i'm using Redux 

Comment: i have 2 application and 1 backEnd , (React & ReactNative)  i want to handle if a user signed using reactNative he can't login using react , thats why i added is_store in the back end  (Rect for Stores )  (ReactNative for Users )

Answer (score 0):

In general, You can pass a state to a child component only. You can not pass a state from a child to its parent component.

In order to pass state to a parent component, you need to store that value. You can do it with Redux. Which stores the values and you can get that value in any component.

Comment: i'm actually using Redux , the only thing i want to use "is_store" to Handle authentication from frontEnd , i have 2 application and 1 backEnd , (React & ReactNative)  i want to handle if a user signed using reactNative he can't login using react , thats why i added is_store in the back end  (Rect for Stores )  (ReactNative for Users )

Comment: You can store a token to the server end. You need to save a token when the user login into the system. Next time when the user tries to login with another method you need to check if the token already exists or not. If the token does not exist then permit to login with another device and if the token exists then show a message that you are already logged in on another device. this attempt will logout you from another device.